ADX Kusto how to merge two large tables
I have a simple case, one huge table in the database and another table which comes from a CSV file which has a mapping with the ID from the first table and another column which I want to append to the first table based on the ID.
TableA
| join kind=inner external_table(Table2) on ID

However I am getting a Query Limit Exceeded, either due to too many queries or due to too large size. I know I can add some commands and change those limits, but when I try to estimate_data_size of this operation it returns 98gbs, which sounds like a lot.
How am I supposed to perform such an operation on this big data?

Based on the query in the question, the Query Limit Exceeded error would be due to the query trying to return all 98 Gbs, which is probably not the behaviour you want. The query as stated right now says to take large tableA and large table2 and return all results. If you only subset your results does the query still complete?
TableA
| join kind=inner external_table(Table2) on ID
| take 1000


You could just project a smaller amount of data you really need or filter with additional where clauses, like this:
TableA
| project timestamp, ID
| where ID > 1000
| join kind=inner (
| external_table(Table2)
| project timestamp, ID) on ID

